# changing variables of a separate R script in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a set of scripts which are run from below, with aspects of the final output influenced by lines 2-4

```
setwd() 
inputyear = ""
inputmonth = ""
dataType = ""

source("1.R")
source("2.R")
source("3.R") 
source("4.R")
source("5.R")

#input required file name
saveWorkbook(wb, "Workbook.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

I'd like to be able to change the input year, input month, dataType and the name of the workbook produced by the source() 1-5, from a shiny app, and then run the respective files and generate the excel file.

So far I have the following code, which does not produce any errors, but does not function as desired.
I have only included the 'server' section of the code to save space, and this is the part I need help with if possible;

```
ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),

                      tags$head(
                        tags$style(HTML(
                          ".shiny-output-error-validation {
                          color; green;
                          }
                          "))
                        ),

                      basicPage(
                        headerPanel("Workbook"),
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("inputmonth","Select Publication Month",c("JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC")),
                          selectInput("inputyear","Select Year",c("2018/19","2019/20","2020/21")),
                          selectInput("dataType","Select Version",c("provisional","final"))),
                        textInput("WorkBookName","Enter File Name (include .xlsx)"),
                        actionButton("Generate", "Generate Workbook"))
                        ))


server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$Generate, {
    validate(need(input$WorkBookName != "", "Please enter file name"))

    req(input$inputmonth, input$inputyear, input$dataType, input$WorkBookName)

    inputyear = input$inputmonth
    inputmonth = input$inputyear
    dataType = input$dataType

    source("1.R",local = TRUE)
    source("2.R", local = TRUE)
    source("3.R", local = TRUE) 
    source("4.R", local = TRUE)
    source("5.R", local = TRUE)


    saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(input$WorkBookName, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I alter the server script to get the desired functionality?

edit: Full script added, sourced names removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll somehow need to trigger the execution of your reactive code. Reactive code only is executed if it was invalidated. Please see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/execution-scheduling.html) for further information.

In the following app the code will be executed once the `Save Workbook` button is clicked.
I don't know your UI and sourced R-scripts, so you might want to replace here accordingly:

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),

  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML(".shiny-output-error-validation {
                          color; green;
                          }
                          ")
  )),
  basicPage(
    headerPanel("Workbook"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "inputmonth",
        "Select Publication Month",
        toupper(month.abb)
      ),
      selectInput("inputyear", "Select Year", c("2018/19", "2019/20", "2020/21")),
      selectInput("dataType", "Select Version", c("provisional", "final"))
    ),
    textInput("WorkBookName", "Enter File Name (include .xlsx)"),
    actionButton("Generate", "Generate Workbook"),
    uiOutput("test")
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Generate, {
    req(input$inputmonth,
        input$inputyear,
        input$dataType,
        input$WorkBookName)

    inputyear = input$inputmonth
    inputmonth = input$inputyear
    dataType = input$dataType

    # source("1.R", local = TRUE)
    # source("2.R", local = TRUE)
    # source("3.R", local = TRUE)
    # source("4.R", local = TRUE)
    # source("5.R", local = TRUE)
    # 
    # saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(input$WorkBookName, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
    output$test <- renderUI("Everything fine...")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work but gives the following error: Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: That's something that quite likely happens in the sourced files you didn't provide. You might want to place a `browser()` call in your code to debug or share more of your code.

Comment: Ok thanks,the sourced files run fine when not being run through shiny, which code would be useful to share to get to the issue? The whole shiny script?

Comment: Full script added, could the validate(need(input$WorkBookName != "" be causing the error?  I have seen other posts where NA seems to cause similar errors?

Comment: No `validate` won't be the issue. Nevertheless, you might want to delete it since it's only working in render*-functions not in reactives or observers. The issue is somewhere in your sourced R-scripts (an if-clause getting `NULL` or `NA`). I updated my answer. After commenting out the `source` calls everything is working fine (provide a workbook name and press generate).

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked and the script worked fine the first time it was run, but the second time of wanting to run it I got the following error ```Warning: Error in detach: invalid 'name' argument``` I tried to unload the packages then re run but this didn't work, any suggestion would be really useful

Comment: You will need to trace where `detach` is used an check what you are passing to it's name argument. `detach` however isn't used in the above script (will be one of your sourced files again).